My Heros height which is 100vh shrinks when using a link to scroll to a different section
My Heros height is 100vh. When ai use the header to scroll to a different section, and then scroll manually to the top again, the 100vh height shrunk a bit. The bug fixes itself when scrolling to Home again with the link. I use Nextjs with Tailwind.
Hero Code:
<div className="tw-h-[100vh] tw-grid tw-text-center" id="home">
<other-stuff>
</div>

Link to the page to try it out:
Https://pascal-burri.com
I expected the height not to change when scrolling to a link.
